# pygame муравей Ленгтона не работает на классах

Tags: python, python-3.x, ооп, pygame

господа. Я решил сделать классического муравья Ленгтона, используя `pygame` и классы для другой задумки. Смысл в том, что перенеся основной код в структуру классов, муравей перестал визуализироваться, однако если я вывожу в консоль координаты, то консоль показывает, что муравей ходит.
Представляю две версии кода, одна - неработаующая на классах, вторая работающая, но без классов
Программа на классах:

```
import pygame

width, height = 800, 600
display = pygame.display.set_mode((width,height))
pygame.init()
qg = 2
x, y = 300, 300
display.fill((255,255,255))
directions = ((0, -1), (-1, 0), (0, 1), (1, 0))
direction = 0
a = 0

class ant():
    qg = 2
    directions = ((0, -1), (-1, 0), (0, 1), (1, 0))
    dx = 0
    dy = 0
    
    def __init__(self, x, y, direction, a):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.direction = direction
        self.a = 0
        

        
    def turn(self):
        '''print(ant.qg, ant.dx, ant.dy, ant.a, self.x, self.y, self.direction)'''
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                pygame.quit()
                quit()

        # update position
        ant.dx, ant.dy = ant.directions[self.direction]
        self.x += ant.dx * ant.qg
        self.y += ant.dy * ant.qg
        '''
        try:
            a = display.get_at((x, y))
        except:
            break
        '''
        if self.a == (255, 255, 255, 255):
            # White square
            pygame.draw.rect(display,(255,0,0),(self.x,self.y,ant.qg,ant.qg))     # paint red
            self.direction = (self.direction + 1) % 4                               # turn left
        else:
            # Red square
            pygame.draw.rect(display,(255,255,255),(self.x,self.y,ant.qg,ant.qg)) # paint white
            self.direction = (self.direction + 3) % 4                               # turn right
        pygame.display.update()
        
kolya = ant(x, y, direction, a)
while True:
    kolya.turn()
```

Программа без классов:

```
import pygame
width, height = 800, 600
display = pygame.display.set_mode((width,height))
pygame.init()
qg = 2
x, y = 300, 300
display.fill((255,255,255))
directions = ((0, -1), (-1, 0), (0, 1), (1, 0))
direction = 0
while True:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            quit()

    # update position
    dx, dy = directions[direction]
    x += dx * qg
    y += dy * qg

    try:
        a = display.get_at((x, y))
    except:
        break

    if a == (255, 255, 255, 255):
        # White square
        pygame.draw.rect(display,(255,0,0),(x,y,qg,qg)) # paint red
        direction = (direction + 1) % 4                 # turn left
    else:
        # Red square
        pygame.draw.rect(display,(255,255,255),(x,y,qg,qg)) # paint white
        direction = (direction + 3) % 4                     # turn right
    pygame.display.update()
    
    
print ("end")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Дело было в закоментированной мной строке `self.a = display.get_at((self.x, self.y))` - это строка считывает пиксель